# Cryptography: converting C function to python

Tags: python, c, cryptography

I am trying to solve a cryptography problem (https://callicode.fr/pydefis/Reverse/txt), the alghorithm make use of the following C function (F1). 
I don't know C, I tried to convert it to python(F2) without success. Thank you in advance for letting me know what I did wrong.

**F1:**

```
void Encrypt(unsigned char key[20], unsigned char *pPlainBuffer, unsigned char *pCipherBuffer, unsigned int nLength) 
{
int nKeyPos = 0;
unsigned int n;
unsigned char KeyA = 0;

if ((pPlainBuffer != NULL) && (pCipherBuffer != NULL)) {
for (n = 0; n < 20; n++) 
  KeyA ^= key[n];
  nKeyPos = KeyA % 20;
for (n = 0; n < nLength; n++) {
  pCipherBuffer[n] = pPlainBuffer[n]^(key[nKeyPos]*KeyA);
  KeyA += pCipherBuffer[n];
  nKeyPos = pCipherBuffer[n] % 20;
}
 }
}
```

**F2:**

```
def Encrypt(plainText, key):  # plainText is a list of hexadecimals representing ascii 
                              # characters, key is a list of int size 20  each int 
                              # beetween 0 and 255
    keyA = 0

    for n in range(20):
        keyA ^= key[n]

    nKeyPos = KeyA % 20

    for n in range(len(plainText)):
         codedText[n] = plainText[n]^(key[nKeyPos]*KeyA)
         keyA += codedText[n]
         nKeyPos = codedText[n] % 20
```

Comment: Don't "convert". Read the specs and reimplement from scratch.

Comment: In C, indentation does not matter to the compiler, but it sure matters for humans. Your C-code is indented misleadingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have many issues... the most glaring being that python integers are not constrained to a byte width by default so you must explicitly set the width

additionally you must convert the letters to numbers in python as they are fundamentally different things (in C/c++ letters are really just numbers)

```
def Encrypt(plainText, key):  # plainText is a list of hexadecimals representing ascii 
                              # characters, key is a list of int size 20  each int                                   # beetween 0 and 255
    keyA = 0    
    for letter in key:
        keyA ^= ord(letter) # conver letter to number    
    keyA = keyA & 0xFF # fix width to one byte
    key = itertools.cycle(key) # repeate forever
    codedText = ""
    for letter,keyCode in zip(plainText,key):
         xorVal = (ord(keyCode) * keyA) & 0xFF # make one byte wide
         newLetter = chr((ord(letter) ^ xorVal )&0xFF) # make one byte wide

         codedText += newLetter
         keyA += ord(newLetter)
         keyA = keyA&0xFF # keep it one byte wide
```

Comment: I did not understood your solution at first reading but now I think I do.  So if I understand correctly in C a char is 1 byte long and each time an operation involves a char the result is kept 1 byte long. So it means the following would be true:    `code` char keyA * 255  =  (char keyA * 255)  & 0xFF = (char keyA * 255) %256  `code`   Is that correct ?Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little working example:

```
def Encrypt(key, pPlainBuffer):
    nKeyPos = 0
    KeyA = 0

    if pPlainBuffer is not None:
        pCipherBuffer = []
        for n in range(20):
            KeyA = KeyA ^ key[n]
        nKeyPos = KeyA % 20

        for n in range(len(pPlainBuffer)):
            pCipherBuffer.append(pPlainBuffer[n] ^ (key[nKeyPos] * KeyA))
            KeyA += pCipherBuffer[n]
            nKeyPos = pCipherBuffer[n] % 20

        return pCipherBuffer


def Decrypt(key, pCipherBuffer):
    nKeyPos = 0
    KeyA = 0

    if pCipherBuffer is not None:
        pPlainBuffer = []
        for n in range(20):
            KeyA ^= key[n]
        nKeyPos = KeyA % 20

        for n in range(len(pCipherBuffer)):
            pPlainBuffer.append(pCipherBuffer[n] ^ (key[nKeyPos] * KeyA))
            KeyA += pCipherBuffer[n]
            nKeyPos = pCipherBuffer[n] % 20

        return pPlainBuffer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random

    key = [random.randint(0, 255) for k in range(20)]

    pPlainBuffer = [ord(c) for c in "this is the unencrypted message"]
    a = Encrypt(key, pPlainBuffer)
    b = Decrypt(key, a)

    print("-"*80)
    print("Encrypted message")
    print("-"*80)
    print(":".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in a))
    print("-"*80)
    print("Decrypted message")
    print("-"*80)
    print("".join([chr(c) for c in b]))

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Encrypted message
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # 1ba:2678:197df9:bec4844:2d163e70c:1d01cf925ab:45512ab14a9b:4724251445d50:550934523b78ca:1f34a7cfbb7db6a1:1bfb485c731bcdb713:161112a22402868312ad:b1696bc757013314e2975:531cf11bdcc471dc32befef:a2627edf4f99a01240ba016f:839c3758163127edc2e955cc63:100437038699e709cce258a3ed1b:6c7fa638eaa735df4ae48a03e32a9:58911d1d6ea1c00863052f0fa160a0d:2c7f52a5aa98fec79d57f011bf256acf0:22559e3d644a5d56f620427531855711f90:81693c9711311b3cfe601f0f44c5ec6c8eb9:6a628fdbfce204d77db6eb221a161b683dee6a:c86f7e57fa208eaff7fbe01b26048cae230f1a8:308b00994e93e28e9e0f004693351a122c7da861d:2bc2e905f06bc052ef96e3dd7d68389e9df11483546:9717a6cd2ce3ac9b8757110bab10b835b11adda93df2:12072f89ef89b60cbd3d4c3735dda19daddbeecfd47b5d:1084c8b9afea8c4ece5432ef4130712f4f9a5a403acac323:27679b285784a6a9f1d42189acfc9433655c776e5ce16d191:1c6f807e0f27d47ad8ee72ba6740cb5dee4d918da413efe2f6d
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Decrypted message
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # this is the unencrypted message
```

That'd be almost a 1:1 c++ rewrited version but if you wanted a more pythonic one:

```
def encrypt(key, plain_buffer):
    key_pos = 0
    key_a = 0

    cipher_buffer = []

    if plain_buffer is not None:
        for k in key:
            key_a = key_a ^ k
        key_pos = key_a % 20

        for n, d in enumerate(plain_buffer):
            cipher_buffer.append(d ^ (key[key_pos] * key_a))
            key_a += cipher_buffer[n]
            key_pos = cipher_buffer[n] % 20

    return cipher_buffer


def decrypt(key, cipher_buffer):
    key_pos = 0
    key_a = 0

    plain_buffer = []

    if cipher_buffer is not None:
        for k in key:
            key_a ^= k
        key_pos = key_a % 20

        for n, d in enumerate(cipher_buffer):
            plain_buffer.append(d ^ (key[key_pos] * key_a))
            key_a += cipher_buffer[n]
            key_pos = cipher_buffer[n] % 20

    return plain_buffer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random
    random.seed(1)

    key = [random.randint(0, 255) for k in range(20)]

    plain_buffer = [ord(c) for c in "this is the unencrypted message"]
    a = encrypt(key, plain_buffer)
    b = decrypt(key, a)

    print("-" * 80)
    print("Encrypted message")
    print("-" * 80)
    print(":".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in a))
    print("-" * 80)
    print("Decrypted message")
    print("-" * 80)
    print("".join([chr(c) for c in b]))
```

Although is not using unsigned chars, that's why the encrypted message looks that big.

Comment: Im 99% sure he wants to encrypt a message for the C/C++ to decrypt ... or vice versa ... as such this probably wont quite cut it ... +1 all the same since this works fine as long as he encrypts and decrypts here in python ... (but its really not the same as what he is trying to implement)

Comment: see my solution below (val&0xFF) should constrain it to one byte :P

Comment: they are functionally equivelent ;P ...since python only supports arbitrary width you must force it using bit stuffs

Comment: Actually, I want to have a python function that would for a given key and plain text, give the same coded message as would the C function. So indeed I think that some module % 256 or &0xFF is involved somewhere